# selecting radio button by default in angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Please find the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XNuUsSxSvdxoGzH80znU?p=preview) for radio buttons. I am expecting when I select radio button, the selected object from  `$scope.itemList` to be assigned to `selectedItemDetails`  but it is not happening. And also by default when the page loads I want the default radio button to be selected based on `var tagNumTobeSelectedByDefault = 2;` i.e., `"Gety of House"` to be selected by default, how can I do it?

I am getting the index of the object to be selected from the list as follows:

```
var indexObjectTobeSet = $scope.itemList.map(function(x) {
    return x.tagNum;
}).indexOf(tagNumTobeSelectedByDefault);
```

But failing to set that particular radio  button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are declaring `selectedItemDetails` as an empty literal `{}`, you do not have a specific binding. Declare a property the `ng-model` can attach to :

```js
$scope.selectedItemDetails = { selected : null }
```

and

```html
<input type="radio" ng-model="selectedItemDetails.selected" name="eachCat" data-ng-value="eachCat">
```

Then it works. Now you can also set the default selected radio item with

```
$scope.selectedItemDetails = { selected : $scope.itemList[3]  }
```

**http://plnkr.co/edit/9hVxlhzvCmx3PIsbImVD?p=preview**

Comment: But by default "Gety of House" was not getting set in the radio button even if I replace  $scope.selectedItemDetails = { selected : null } with   $scope.selectedItemDetails = { selected :  {
    "subNum": 1222,
    "tagName": "Gety of House",
    "tagNum": 2,
    "slList": null
  } }

Comment: @MadasuK - even if you have similar literals they are different objects! Use selected : `$scope.itemList[index]`. You are iterating over `itemList` with `ngRepeat`, so use references from `itemList` when you set the default selected radio button.

Answer (score 2):

You don't set the index, you set `selectedItemDetails`' value to the actual object you want selected in the `$scope.itemList` array. Thus,

```
$scope.selectedItemDetails = $scope.itemList.filter(function(item) { return item.tagNum === tagNumTobeSelectedByDefault; })[0];
```

should work (just remember to put it *after* the `$scope.itemList` definition). You might even want to consider moving the `itemList` object into a service or constant.

Comment: default selection is working fine but after that if I change the radio button selection, "selectedItemDetails" is not reflecting the change.

Comment: It seems to be working with the solution you have now (replacing `ng-model="selectedItemDetails"` with `ng-model="selectedItemDetails.selected"` and possibly the above line of code with `$scope.selectedItemDetails = {selected: $scope.itemList.filter(function(item) { return item.tagNum === tagNumTobeSelectedByDefault; })[0]};`. This is one of the reasons Angular best practices say that your `ng-model` should always contain a `.`(dot).